# How can I get an output only when an exact period of 3 months has passed?

Tags: php

I want to figure out, when my date is exact 3 months.
Here is my code:

```
                $curdate=date_create(date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));

                $date1=date_create(date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($check1)));
                $checkd1=date_diff($date1,$curdate);

                $format1 = '';

                if ($checkd1->y > 0) {$format1 .= '%y years';}          
                if ($checkd1->m > 0) {$format1 .= '%m months ';}
                if ($checkd1->d >= 0) {$format1 .= '%d days';}
                $checkr1 = $checkd1->format($format1);



                $date2=date_create(date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($check2)));
                $checkd2=date_diff($date2,$curdate);
                $format2 = '';

                if ($checkd2->y > 0) {$format2 .= '%y years ';}         
                if ($checkd2->m > 0) {$format2 .= '%m months ';}
                if ($checkd2->d >= 0) {$format2 .= '%d days';}

                $checkr2 = $checkd2->format($format2);


                $date3=date_create(date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($check3)));
                $checkd3=date_diff($date3,$curdate);
                $format3 = '';

                if ($checkd3->y > 0) {$format3 .= '%y years ';}     
                if ($checkd3->m > 0) {$format3 .= '%m months ';}
                if ($checkd3->d >= 0) {$format3 .= '%d days';}
                $checkr3 = $checkd3->format($format3);


               if ($checkd1->m = 3 AND $checkd1->y < 1 AND $checkd1->d < 1) { echo ' Check1:This date is exact 3 months: '.$checkr1.'<br>';}
               if ($checkd2->m = 3 AND $checkd2->y < 1 AND $checkd2->d < 1) { echo ' Check2:This date is exact 3 months: '.$checkr2.'<br>';}
               if ($checkd3->m = 3 AND $checkd3->y < 1 AND $checkd3->d < 1) { echo ' Check3:This date is exact 3 months: '.$checkr3.'<br>';}
```

Unfortunately my result is:

```
Check1:This date is exact 3 months: 0 days.
Check2:This date is exact 3 months: 3 months 0 days
```

But this is obviously not true. My result should be:

```
 Check2:This date is exact 3 months: 3 months 0 days
```

Do you know what I did wrong?

Comment: Why your check's is the same in all three situations and you didn't create a function or something for it?

Comment: @Guiherme Lopes Thank you, yes I thought about this, but unfortunately I do not know how to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without reading the first part, this is probably your problem:

```
if ($checkd1->m = 3 AND ...
```

Here you are assigning the value instead of comparing.

To check for `3`, you need:

```
if ($checkd1->m === 3 AND ...
```

Comment: Oh yes! This was the problem, thank you! Is it also possible to write `$checkd1->m == 3 AND` and if yes, what is the difference?

Comment: @Jarla `==` would work here, but `===` also checks if the types are the same, so `2 == "2"` but `2 !== "2"` or in other words: `2 === "2"` would return false.

Comment: @Jarla there is one diference between `==` and `===`, the first one, just compare if it's equal, the second, compares the type and if it's equal.

Answer (score 1):

You can Also utilize following function :

```
<?php

function diffInDays($date1,$date2){
    $datetime1 = date_create($date1);
    $datetime2 = date_create($date2);
    $interval = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);
    return $interval->format('%R%a days');
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I will check it out